# How to call a function from the value of tree attribute

Tags: function, view, colors, tree, field

I have my tree view:

> ```
> <tree string="quality" colors="red:expire_date &lt; **current_date**;">
>   <field name="code"/>
>   <field name="supplier"/>
>   <field name="approved"/>
>   <field name="invoice"/>
>   <field name="**expire_date**"/>
> </tree>
> ```

Thar works sussesful. In attribute "colors" I want to call a function:

def **fecha_restada**(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        return (datetime.today() - relativedelta(days=10)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

Itryed:  but it sends me error: fecha_restada is not definied. But my function is returning the right value, but I can't to call it from there.

If I resolve this, after I'll put the parameter expired_date on call the function and sustitute datetime.today() by my expire_date parametter.

...Thanks 4 ur time !!!!